# Usage of 가족상황 vs. 혼인관계

Tags: word-usage

In my textbook, both `가족상황` and `혼인관계` are translated as "marital status".
Now, I'm not sure how to use them. `혼인관계` is listed under personal information, so I guess it is used in a context of a certificate or an ID (so, in a written form?).

When would you use `가족상황`? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116221/discussion-on-question-by-xordak-usage-of--vs-).

Answer (score 1):

가족상황 is family relation. If you were to directly translate each word, it would be 가족(family)+상황(situation). However, it basically refers to the family relation. To add more, family is 가족 and relation is 관계.

we do not quite use the word 가족상황 in our daily life, but I would assume that the textbook was referring to the family relations instead.

For example, there's 가족 관계 증명서 which is an official document that the government issue to prove your family registry.
**가족 관계 증명서** is officially translated as **Family Relations Certificate** in English. This document contains information about your direct families such as Father, Mother, Spouse, and Child. So, 가족 관계 refers to your relation to the direct families.

**혼인 관계** is **marital status**. Again, there's 혼인 관계 증명서 which is an official document that the government issue to prove your marital status. **혼인 관계 증명서** is officially translated as **Marriage Relation Certificate**. This document contains information about yourself and your spouses only. Your kids or any other family members would not be addressed here. So 혼인 관계 refers to your marriage relation.

Comment: There is no evidence that `가족상황` means `Family relation` or is equivalent to it. My guess is that the textbook misused the word `가족상황` in the place it's supposed to say `가족관계`. `가족상황` is likely a translated vocabulary for `Family status`--that doesn't have much to do with `Family relation`--as defined in [Human Rights Code, R.S.O. 1990, c. H.19](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/90h19) and used by a paper called [A Study on Family Status Discrimination in terms of Recognition Paradigm (인정(認定) 패러다임에 비추어 본 가족상황차별 담론 분석)](http://dspace.ewha.ac.kr/handle/2015.oak/179762).

Comment: [Human Rights Code, R.S.O. 1990, c. H.19](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/90h19) reads: “family status” means the status of being in a parent and child relationship; (“état familial”)

Answer (score 0):

가족상황 basically asking about family "situation" -- single parent, divorced, living with grandparent(s) or any relatives as guardians, with or without having parents (not in contact or they passed), or if one is orphan.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 가족상황 is being used in daily life. If I see "가족상황" on the document to fill out, I would guess what kind of family information the doc requires based on the following columns.. and I assume it could be your father/mother/spouse/child's name, age, etc etc but it could be something different as well. e.g, live together or not.. or even means martial status.

However, 혼인관계 is literally means "Martial Status".